# Multiple item data. Show the data as clicked in the dynamically modal with react-native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-modal

FOOD> PIZZA> clicking on any pizza opens a modal. I want to show the information of the pizza clicked in this modal. I looked at many similar examples but I could not get out of it. So I need help. I add some parts of the code below. At the same time, the code is available in the expo and the link below

snack.expo.io/@ibrahimyolbir/e48b05

**accordion**

```js
<Accordion
  dataArray={this.state.menus}
  animation={true}
  expanded={true}
  renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
  renderContent={this._renderContent}
/>
```

**my open modal button in the render content**

```js
onPress={this.triggerModal(food)}
```

```js
_renderContent = (item) => {
  return (
    <List>
      {
        item.food.map((food, index) => {
          return (
            <ListItem style={{
              backgroundColor: "#f0f0f5",
              padding: 10,
              marginLeft: 0,
              paddingRight: 10,
              fontStyle: "italic",
              listStyleType: "none",
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "space-between"
            }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.triggerModal(food)}
                style={{
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  justifyContent: "space-between"
                }}
              >
                <Left style={{
                  maxWidth: 57
                }}>
                  <Thumbnail source={require("../assets/images/left-food-icon.png")} />
                </Left>
                <Body>
                  <Text >{food.name}</Text>
                  <Text note >{food.description}</Text>
                </Body>
                <Right>
                  <Text >{food.price} :-</Text>
                </Right>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </ListItem>
          )
        }
        )
      }
    </List>
  );
}
```

**MODAL**

```js
<Modal
  style={{ marginTop: 122 }}
  isVisible={this.state.display}
  visible={this.state.display}
  onSwipeComplete={() => this.setState({ isVisible: false })}
  onSwipeThreshold={1}
  swipeDirection="down"
  animationType="slide"
  onRequestClose={() => {
    Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
  }}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
    <Text>Hello!</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.closeDisplay} style={{ marginTop: 40, marginLeft: 150 }}>
      <Text> CLOSE MODAL </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    {/* <Text> {this.state.menus} </Text> */}
  </View>
</Modal>
```

[image: My Json data file]

[image: Food screen]

Comment: please share the xpo link?

Comment: I dont know why but modal doesnt work in the expo but you can see the all code.Screens>foodjs>   https://snack.expo.io/@ibrahimyolbir/b82615

Comment: @GauravRoy 
Did you open the page?

Comment: give me 15 mins

Comment: Hi @GauravRoy i changed the code you can see here the latest code if you have time thanks. https://snack.expo.io/@ibrahimyolbir/e48b05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way can be:

1)Create a new state

```
currentChildData:[],
currentParentData:[],
```

2)Pass parent id and child index in onPress event

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.triggerModal(item.id,index)}
```

3)Using that passed index and parent id,we can extract relevant information about(to be clicked item) from menus state

```
triggerModal = (ParentIndex,childIndex) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
    let ParentData=[...prevState.menus].find(each=>each.id==ParentIndex)
      return {
        display: true,
        currentChildData: ParentData.food[childIndex],
        currentParentData: ParentData,
      }
    });
  }
```

4)Now we have information of(to be clicked item) in our state. We then can use it like (name of item shown below) inside Modal

```
 <Text>{this.state.currentChildData.name}</Text>
```

Working Code: https://snack.expo.io/By_QVbPMI

Comment: Hi Dipesh! Thank you very much for your help. I applied it as you wrote. But it brings wrong ID every time. I have added new images above 1. view of json data file 2. food screen

Comment: Everything is working fine now, only there is a problem that comes to me the information of the categories(Parents) right now. I need child's information.              "id": "94905070-bc1d-11e9-b1f7-61a58a76a9a8",
            "name": "PIZZA",
            "food": [
                {
                    "id": "61a58a76a9a82",
                    "name": "Margherita",
                    "price": "89",
                    "description": "Tomatsås, mozzarella, parmesanost"
                },

Comment: what is your latest code right now.Provide expo link.

Comment: here is the latest code https://snack.expo.io/@ibrahimyolbir/e48b05. I understand  what is the problem. It takes first the parent as an index. In my incoming data, there are food categories in the menu and below it are food types.{"menus": [{"id": "1","name": "PIZZA","food": [   {"id": "61a58a76a9a82","name": "Margherita","price": "89",
                     "description": "Tomatsås, mozzarella, parmesanost"},
Here I need to take the parent's index of the food type and then get the child's

Comment: so the problem is fixed?

Comment: No because i take here this.state.menus[this.state.selectedPost] this is categories(menus-PIZZA) index. i need to foods(MARGHERITA) index

Comment: There is no items in menus state right now in your code.You could push your latest working code so that i could test myself and help you

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@ibrahimyolbir/respay   Yes because the data coming from the server. I did put some data as array you can check the code now. As i said before modal doesnt work in the expo. But when you cliecked a item you can see the currentdata.name below .

Comment: Helllo Ibrahim,As far as I have understood your question,you want Pizza information and Pasta Piemontese information inside modal when you click Pasta Piemontese.Am I right?

Comment: If that is the case...I have implemented logic you needed.Here is expo link(https://snack.expo.io/By_QVbPMI)

Comment: OMG. amazing. Thank you very very very much. @Dipesh I just needed to show child information. Now its working prefect.

Comment: Glad to help you.Cheers :)

Comment: Hi @Dipesh . If you have time. i want ask a question on the same topic

Comment: @IbrahimYolbir sorry for the late reply.I didn't notice it till today.Do you have any question still?

Comment: Yes the problem continus. I would be grateful if you. have time and help me

Answer (score 0):

U missed the key from mapped array in a ListItem component. Add it as a prop key={Index} .
Also U need item from map as argument in ur onPress, cuz u need to push visited/selected elements to the state. `{()=>this.openModal(itemFromMap)}`
And then u can manipulate with data like u need. 
As I can understood u have array of objects. `Object.keys(itemFromMap).map(...`
And return data to the needed part of ur modalInnerContainer.

Comment: Hi Denis! I did what you said but I will be very happy if you explain what I have to do next

Comment: Now its coming data but not needed data you can check my code here  snack.expo.io/@ibrahimyolbir/e48b05.  Screens>FoodScreensjs and . I have screenhoots for the my jsondata and view food screen

Comment: No.Now the problem is;  It takes first the parent as an index. In my incoming data, there are food categories in the menu and below it are food types. I want show Food types (child for the categories for ex: PIZZA are the one category and  Margherita child for PIZZA) informations in the modal

Comment: I ve just updated my answer. Try and let me know if it’s solve the problem.